# Изменение размера Expander-а

Tags: c#, wpf

1. Есть ли возможность изменить иконку и ее размер в експандере?
2. Можно ли в button вложить expander, так чтобы expander видно не было, но при нажатии на кнопку експандер срабатывал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполните привязку изображения в expander до самого "низкого" уровня с помощью свойства "Tag". На счет размера не подскажу...

```
<Style x:Key="имя_стиля" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <!--Здесь свойства вашей кнопки-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Expander Background="Transparent"
                              BorderBrush="Transparent"
                              BorderThickness="0"
                              Tag="{TemplateBinding Tag}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/> <!--А вот и сама привязка-->
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Далее в вашей программе, где вам надо, там и меняете свойство "Tag" у кнопки указывая ссылку на иконку.

Comment: меняется не иконка експандера, а то что появляется когда на експандер нажимаешь.

Comment: @Lightness, возможно я не так понял ваш вопрос, подскажите, чего именно вы пытаетесь добиться? Каков ваш желаемый конечный результат? Возможно есть другие пути достижения этого результата...

Comment: мне нужна кнопка, при нажатии на которую будет выезжать информация точно так же как и с експандера. Но обязательно должна быть возможность менять иконку и размер иконки этой кнопки.

Comment: @Lightness, Я бы на вашем месте создал бы свой [UserControl](http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/Template/level18/18_2.php), в нем определил бы несколько дополнительных [DependencyProperties](http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/base_WPF/level4/4_3.php) от значения которых и зависили размеры иконки и сама иконка, затем в `xaml` разметке окна создал бы `xmlns` ссылку на пространство имен с вашим UserControl, и добавил его в окно. Как то так...